# Rails nested_form doubts on documentation

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

Hi im using gem "nested_form" on my rails app.. Actually i was very happyu when i found this in the Documentation :

```
Enhanced jQuery JavaScript template

You can override default behavior of inserting new subforms into your form. For example:

    window.nestedFormEvents.insertFields = function(content, assoc, link) {
      return $(link).closest('form').find(assoc + '_fields').append($(content));
    }
```

I need to do that, so i went to application.js and i see the require jquery_nested_form in there.. so i went to "vendor/assets/javascript" and i think i will found the file there but no!, i cant find the file

jquery_nested_form.js

I need to find it to edit that , right? or im missing an easier way?

Also what if i just want to "override default behavior in 1 Id of the form"  and not in all the fields, the documentation is here http://rubydoc.info/gems/nested_form/0.3.2/frames

But i cant figure out how to do what i need..

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to edit the javscript file.

Follow the steps in [nested form](http://rubydoc.info/gems/nested_form/0.3.2/frames)

If you need to override any behavior just add the new javscript code in the application.js file

If you still need to get edit it:

If you do not use the asset pipeline, run this generator to create the JavaScript file.

```
rails g nested_form:install
```

You can then include the generated JavaScript in your layout.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults, "nested_form" %>
```